# Python 3 columnar transposition decryption

Tags: python-3.x

I would an algorith that decrypts a columnar transposition cipher. So far I had no luck creating my own, I understand how you would decrypt it on paper but unable to so on python 3. This is the encryption algorithm i used (in python3).

```
def split_len(seq, length):
   return [seq[i:i + length] for i in range(0, len(seq), length)]

def encode(key, plaintext):

   order = {int(val): num for num, val in enumerate(key)}

   ciphertext = ''
   for index in sorted(order.keys()):
        for part in split_len(plaintext, len(key)):
        try:
            ciphertext += part[order[index]]
        except IndexError:
            continue

return ciphertext

print(encode('213', 'hello_World'))
```

> > This will output eoodhlWll_r
> >     i was thinking of reversing it but no luck.
> >     The key length is decided by the User also the message.

## Note

In the actual design the key is supposed to be letters in the alphabet which is then arranged in alphabetical order. so in my example the key is 213 but in the actual algorithm it'll be some on the lines on bac or pbx.

## On paper

key:213   plain text:hello_world

1. 2 1 3
2. h e l
3. l o _
4. w o r
5. l d

The lowest value is displayed then second and so until all is displayed e.g
1: eood 2:hlwl 3:l_r # the complete cipher text will be eoodhlWll_r

Comment: Could you please, provide a full description of the algorithm and some commentaries to make everybody on the same page? This will help us to understand what's going on and what doesn't work.

Comment: This algorithm is working i just want to turn the cipher text back into plaintext using the same key.

Comment: There're a few chipers which falls under the same name and I can't say which one is yours. I'd ask you again to provide more details to make this question answerable.

Comment: Yea, my mistake in the actual design the key is supposed to be letters in the alphabet  which is then arranged in alphabetical order. so in my example the key is 213 but in the actual algorithm it'll be some on the lines on bac or pbx. I will do my best to do a visual layout:

Comment: Here's a youtube video to show which transposition cipher i am talking about. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_E0M5vfw3g

Comment: Thank you for a description, Could you please to add this to your post. It will be much easier to read in the context